# Heroku error code H10, exited with status 1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, rubygems

Can anyone please shed some light on the heroku logs below? I have deployed a rails app to heroku but I can't work out why it keeps crashing. I've updated the gems file to include the Ruby version (1.8.7).

I'm a novice when it comes to Rails/Ruby so I'm not certain what else I need to provide in this question.

```
$ heroku logs
?[36m2013-04-23T20:25:24.670813+00:00 app[web.1]:?[0m       create  config/locales
?[36m2013-04-23T20:25:24.671180+00:00 app[web.1]:?[0m       create  public/javascripts
?[36m2013-04-23T20:25:24.671180+00:00 app[web.1]:?[0m       create  log
?[36m2013-04-23T20:25:24.670813+00:00 app[web.1]:?[0m       create  doc
?[36m2013-04-23T20:25:24.670813+00:00 app[web.1]:?[0m       create  db
?[36m2013-04-23T20:25:24.671180+00:00 app[web.1]:?[0m       create  lib
?[36m2013-04-23T20:25:24.671180+00:00 app[web.1]:?[0m       create  script/performance
?[36m2013-04-23T20:25:24.670813+00:00 app[web.1]:?[0m       create  app/controllers
?[36m2013-04-23T20:25:24.671180+00:00 app[web.1]:?[0m       create  public/images
?[36m2013-04-23T20:25:24.671405+00:00 app[web.1]:?[0m       create  test/performance
?[36m2013-04-23T20:25:24.671180+00:00 app[web.1]:?[0m       create  lib/tasks
?[36m2013-04-23T20:25:24.671180+00:00 app[web.1]:?[0m       create  public/stylesheets
?[36m2013-04-23T20:25:24.671405+00:00 app[web.1]:?[0m       create  test/unit
?[36m2013-04-23T20:25:24.671405+00:00 app[web.1]:?[0m       create  vendor
?[36m2013-04-23T20:25:24.671405+00:00 app[web.1]:?[0m       create  vendor/plugins
?[36m2013-04-23T20:25:24.671405+00:00 app[web.1]:?[0m       create  tmp/sessions
?[36m2013-04-23T20:25:24.671405+00:00 app[web.1]:?[0m       create  tmp/sockets
?[36m2013-04-23T20:25:24.671180+00:00 app[web.1]:?[0m       create  test/fixtures
?[36m2013-04-23T20:25:24.671180+00:00 app[web.1]:?[0m       create  test/integration
?[36m2013-04-23T20:25:24.671180+00:00 app[web.1]:?[0m       create  test/functional
?[36m2013-04-23T20:25:24.671405+00:00 app[web.1]:?[0m       create  Rakefile
?[36m2013-04-23T20:25:24.671405+00:00 app[web.1]:?[0m       create  tmp/pids
?[36m2013-04-23T20:25:24.671405+00:00 app[web.1]:?[0m       create  README
?[36m2013-04-23T20:25:24.671405+00:00 app[web.1]:?[0m       create  tmp/cache
?[36m2013-04-23T20:25:24.671625+00:00 app[web.1]:?[0m       create  config/routes.rb
?[36m2013-04-23T20:25:24.671625+00:00 app[web.1]:?[0m       create  config/initializers/backtrace_silencers.rb
?[36m2013-04-23T20:25:24.671625+00:00 app[web.1]:?[0m       create  app/controllers/application_controller.rb
?[36m2013-04-23T20:25:24.671625+00:00 app[web.1]:?[0m       create  config/initializers/inflections.rb
?[36m2013-04-23T20:25:24.671625+00:00 app[web.1]:?[0m       create  config/initializers/mime_types.rb
?[36m2013-04-23T20:25:24.671625+00:00 app[web.1]:?[0m       create  config/initializers/new_rails_defaults.rb
?[36m2013-04-23T20:25:24.671625+00:00 app[web.1]:?[0m       create  app/helpers/application_helper.rb
?[36m2013-04-23T20:25:24.671625+00:00 app[web.1]:?[0m       create  config/database.yml
?[36m2013-04-23T20:25:24.671625+00:00 app[web.1]:?[0m       create  config/locales/en.yml
?[36m2013-04-23T20:25:24.671625+00:00 app[web.1]:?[0m       create  config/initializers/session_store.rb
?[36m2013-04-23T20:25:24.671852+00:00 app[web.1]:?[0m       create  config/environment.rb
?[36m2013-04-23T20:25:24.671852+00:00 app[web.1]:?[0m       create  config/environments/development.rb
?[36m2013-04-23T20:25:24.671852+00:00 app[web.1]:?[0m       create  config/boot.rb
?[36m2013-04-23T20:25:24.671852+00:00 app[web.1]:?[0m       create  script/dbconsole
?[36m2013-04-23T20:25:24.671852+00:00 app[web.1]:?[0m       create  config/environments/production.rb
?[36m2013-04-23T20:25:24.671852+00:00 app[web.1]:?[0m       create  config/environments/test.rb
?[36m2013-04-23T20:25:24.672077+00:00 app[web.1]:?[0m       create  test/performance/browsing_test.rb
?[36m2013-04-23T20:25:24.672077+00:00 app[web.1]:?[0m       create  test/test_helper.rb
?[36m2013-04-23T20:25:24.671852+00:00 app[web.1]:?[0m       create  script/about
?[36m2013-04-23T20:25:24.672077+00:00 app[web.1]:?[0m       create  public/404.html
?[36m2013-04-23T20:25:24.672292+00:00 app[web.1]:?[0m       create  public/images/rails.png
?[36m2013-04-23T20:25:24.672292+00:00 app[web.1]:?[0m       create  public/robots.txt
?[36m2013-04-23T20:25:24.672292+00:00 app[web.1]:?[0m       create  public/javascripts/controls.js
?[36m2013-04-23T20:25:24.672292+00:00 app[web.1]:?[0m       create  public/javascripts/effects.js
?[36m2013-04-23T20:25:24.672292+00:00 app[web.1]:?[0m       create  public/javascripts/application.js
?[36m2013-04-23T20:25:24.672077+00:00 app[web.1]:?[0m       create  script/runner
?[36m2013-04-23T20:25:24.672292+00:00 app[web.1]:?[0m       create  public/javascripts/dragdrop.js
?[36m2013-04-23T20:25:24.672077+00:00 app[web.1]:?[0m       create  public/422.html
?[36m2013-04-23T20:25:24.672292+00:00 app[web.1]:?[0m       create  public/javascripts/prototype.js
?[36m2013-04-23T20:25:24.672501+00:00 app[web.1]:?[0m       create  log/server.log
?[36m2013-04-23T20:25:24.671852+00:00 app[web.1]:?[0m       create  script/destroy
?[36m2013-04-23T20:25:24.672077+00:00 app[web.1]:?[0m       create  script/plugin
?[36m2013-04-23T20:25:24.672501+00:00 app[web.1]:?[0m       create  log/development.log
?[36m2013-04-23T20:25:24.672077+00:00 app[web.1]:?[0m       create  script/performance/profiler
?[36m2013-04-23T20:25:24.672292+00:00 app[web.1]:?[0m       create  public/favicon.ico
?[36m2013-04-23T20:25:24.672501+00:00 app[web.1]:?[0m       create  log/production.log
?[36m2013-04-23T20:25:24.671852+00:00 app[web.1]:?[0m       create  script/generate
?[36m2013-04-23T20:25:24.672077+00:00 app[web.1]:?[0m       create  public/500.html
?[36m2013-04-23T20:25:24.672501+00:00 app[web.1]:?[0m       create  log/test.log
?[36m2013-04-23T20:25:24.671852+00:00 app[web.1]:?[0m       create  script/console
?[36m2013-04-23T20:25:24.672292+00:00 app[web.1]:?[0m       create  public/index.html
?[36m2013-04-23T20:25:24.672077+00:00 app[web.1]:?[0m       create  script/server
?[36m2013-04-23T20:25:24.672077+00:00 app[web.1]:?[0m       create  script/performance/benchmarker
?[36m2013-04-23T20:25:24.672292+00:00 app[web.1]:?[0m       create  doc/README_FOR_APP
?[36m2013-04-23T20:25:26.009476+00:00 heroku[web.1]:?[0m Process exited with status 0
?[36m2013-04-23T20:25:26.023526+00:00 heroku[web.1]:?[0m State changed from starting to crashed
?[33m2013-04-23T20:28:26.349480+00:00 heroku[slugc]:?[0m Slug compilation started
?[32m2013-04-23T20:30:14.365781+00:00 heroku[api]:?[0m Release v13 created by support@quba.co.uk
?[32m2013-04-23T20:30:14.416565+00:00 heroku[api]:?[0m Deploy 0cb45cf by support@quba.co.uk
?[36m2013-04-23T20:30:14.502652+00:00 heroku[web.1]:?[0m State changed from crashed to starting
?[33m2013-04-23T20:30:15.173619+00:00 heroku[slugc]:?[0m Slug compilation finished
?[36m2013-04-23T20:30:17.673654+00:00 heroku[web.1]:?[0m Starting process with command `bundle exec rails server -p 37117`
?[36m2013-04-23T20:30:23.040260+00:00 app[web.1]:?[0m   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.2/lib/active_support.rb:56
?[36m2013-04-23T20:30:23.040260+00:00 app[web.1]:?[0m   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.2/bin/../lib/rails_generator.rb:28
?[36m2013-04-23T20:30:23.040260+00:00 app[web.1]:?[0m /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:55: unin
itialized constant ActiveSupport::Dependencies::Mutex (NameError)
?[36m2013-04-23T20:30:23.040260+00:00 app[web.1]:?[0m   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.2/bin/../lib/rails_generator.rb:28:in `require
'
?[36m2013-04-23T20:30:23.040260+00:00 app[web.1]:?[0m   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/bin/rails:23:in `load'
?[36m2013-04-23T20:30:23.040260+00:00 app[web.1]:?[0m   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/bin/rails:23
?[36m2013-04-23T20:30:23.040260+00:00 app[web.1]:?[0m   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.2/bin/rails:14
?[36m2013-04-23T20:30:23.040260+00:00 app[web.1]:?[0m   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.2/lib/active_support.rb:56:in `require
'
?[36m2013-04-23T20:30:23.040260+00:00 app[web.1]:?[0m   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.2/bin/rails:14:in `require'
?[36m2013-04-23T20:30:25.327139+00:00 heroku[web.1]:?[0m Process exited with status 1
?[36m2013-04-23T20:30:25.338958+00:00 heroku[web.1]:?[0m State changed from starting to crashed
?[35m2013-04-23T20:31:00.363764+00:00 heroku[router]:?[0m at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=[APPNAME].herokuapp.com fw
d="81.23.51.18" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
?[36m2013-04-23T20:33:27.934787+00:00 heroku[web.1]:?[0m State changed from crashed to starting
?[36m2013-04-23T20:33:30.123025+00:00 heroku[web.1]:?[0m Starting process with command `bundle exec rails server -p 26457`
?[36m2013-04-23T20:33:31.440611+00:00 app[web.1]:?[0m /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:55: unin
itialized constant ActiveSupport::Dependencies::Mutex (NameError)
?[36m2013-04-23T20:33:31.440919+00:00 app[web.1]:?[0m   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.2/lib/active_support.rb:56
?[36m2013-04-23T20:33:31.440999+00:00 app[web.1]:?[0m   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.2/bin/../lib/rails_generator.rb:28:in `require
'
?[36m2013-04-23T20:33:31.441077+00:00 app[web.1]:?[0m   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.2/bin/../lib/rails_generator.rb:28
?[36m2013-04-23T20:33:31.441156+00:00 app[web.1]:?[0m   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.2/bin/rails:14:in `require'
?[36m2013-04-23T20:33:31.441234+00:00 app[web.1]:?[0m   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.2/bin/rails:14
?[36m2013-04-23T20:33:31.441341+00:00 app[web.1]:?[0m   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/bin/rails:23:in `load'
?[36m2013-04-23T20:33:31.441423+00:00 app[web.1]:?[0m   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/bin/rails:23
?[36m2013-04-23T20:33:31.440812+00:00 app[web.1]:?[0m   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.2/lib/active_support.rb:56:in `require
'
?[36m2013-04-23T20:33:32.797256+00:00 heroku[web.1]:?[0m Process exited with status 1
?[36m2013-04-23T20:33:32.809865+00:00 heroku[web.1]:?[0m State changed from starting to crashed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the error `Uninitialized constant ActiveSupport::Dependencies::Mutex' occurs when you use a too new a version of RubyGems compared to the version of Rails you are using. But Heroku control the version of that so you are a little stuck here. It looks like you are using a really old version of Rails here on Ruby 1.8.7 which is very near it's end of life.

Comment: You can always hack up the heroku ruby buildpack and use an older bundler

Comment: that's true, but being as he's running on 1.8.7 I've assumed he's running on Bamboo stack which doesn't support buildpacks :)

Comment: If that's the case, move to cedar, _then_ play with bulidpacks ;)